# Program is not interactive in NuShell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tty

### Some background

Qemu has a wonderful feature, which allows you to connect its stdio streams to serial ports on the guest. This allows you to connect QEMU's stdio streams to a TTY shell on the guest and interact with it in a way very similar to an SSH session. However, I'm running it through NuShell which seems to do some sort of buffering in an attempt to parse the output. The result of this is that I cannot interact with the guest. The command returns its output only after QEMU's shutdown. The buffer is released, and I see everything, including things I've typed into the non-responsive shell.

However running this same thing in Bash (even if bash is invoked from nushell via the -c flag, and translating the QEMU call accordingly), I get the interactive shell.

### My question

I'm hoping to get this working in NuShell. I don't understand enough about how TTYs differ from piped outputs, but clearly Bash and Qemu treat their stdio streams differently. I'm hoping for some sort of solution which allows me to continue using qemu in NuShell.

How can I either force nushell to stop buffering the output of qemu, or *pipe* the qemu process via some sort of program which behaves similarly to bash in that it does not buffer anything?